# Get Assembly Version in Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, .net-assembly

Is there any way for me to get the version of an assembly or application in Java?

For example, I have a .NET .dll file located in Program Files. I normally call `loadLibrary' on this .dll so I can invoke JNI methods in C++.

```
System.loadLibrary("MyJniAssembly");
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have control over the Java code?

Comment: are you looking for sth. like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8273630/checking-java-assembly

Comment: @Fildor: Yes I have control over the Java code. @Barış: Not exactly. I want to look at my DLL and get its version number, i.e. `1.0.0.0`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood at first. Of course you are in java and calling via jni ... Haven't heard of a standardized way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to expose that information in another native method implemented in the assembly. If you can't do it there, you'd have to create a new assembly with such a method but one that takes a parameter indicating the assembly or type you are interested in.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the easiest way would be to create a new native method to call into a C++ dll, then get the assembly versions there? The C++ dll calls another C# dll, so should I create another new dll that simply returns the version of my C++ or C# dll I am interested in?

Comment: Yes. The method could return the version of any one assembly or return a list of all assemblies loaded at the point in time. Where such a method is implemented depends on which assemblies you can change and if you can call `System.loadLibrary` for a new assembly.

Comment: Of the assemblies I need to check the version of, I have control over all but one. So I am thinking I will implement a new native method in JNI, then the C++ code will return the version numbers of the dll's I am interested in. Does this sound correct?

Comment: Yes. The only caveat is that the method should be called only after the assemblies you are interested in are loaded.

Comment: Ok, I will try this later this afternoon or tomorrow and report back if I have any issues. Thanks for the help Tom.