# Can two different objects like o1 and 02 of same class with different thead like t1 and t2 can they execute synchronized method at the same time

Tags: java, synchronization

Assuming I have two different objects of same class, do they will able to execute the same synchronized method at the same time because the lock is on the object ant not on the method.

Example:

```
MyCLass cc= new MyCLass();
MyCLass cc1= new MyCLass();
```

Now create two thread
t1 --- it will call cc.meth
t2--it will call cc1.meth

```
// in this case t1 thread get lock on object cc and t2 thread get lock  on object cc1.. it will work
synchronized meth(){
}
```

is it correct?

Comment: Please provide a code example of what you are trying to accomplish. Your question is not properly formatted and the question is too vague.

Comment: public static void main(String args[]){
    MyClass pc = new MyClass();
     MyClass pc1 = new MyClass();
        

      Thread t1 =new Thread(() ->  {
                pc.asfd();
            }

        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
            pc1.asfd();
        });
       

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
}
class MyClass{

pubic synchronized void asdf(){
// some statements 
} 

 if there are two different objects of same class they can execute same synchronized method at the same time??

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is answered here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html, that tell that just one instance of the same class is locked while executing a synchronized method, obviously even if executed by a thread.

Comment: so two different objects of the same class can they execute same synchronized method at the same time?? because thread need lock on the object to execute synchronised method in this case, for example, two thread t1 and t2 and two objects o1 and o2 of the same class. t1 get the lock on o1 and t2 get the lock on o2. so now both thread can execute same synchronized method at the same time  because both threads have the lock on the different object . is it correct ??? I hope i am clear now

Comment: @Nikhil you used different terms, but I think that you mean the same thing, so it's correct. Keep in mind that MyClass o1 = new MyClass(); and MyClass o2 = new MyClass(); are 2 different object and 2 different instances of the same class, while  MyClass o1 = new MyClass(); and MyClass o2 = o1; o1 and o2 are the same instance so calling a syncronized method of one lock the other too.

Answer (score 0):

`synchronized` implemented by `monitorenter`. You can see it in your [byte code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315938/is-it-possible-to-view-bytecode-of-class-file). `monitorenter` use the [object monitor](http://www.cs.vsb.cz/benes/vyuka/pre/lab/jvm/monitorenter.htm) - the monitor of the instance of the class (not the class itself). So it is the expected behavior. If two threads try to execute synchronized methods of two **different instances** at the same time, both should not be blocked.

Actually it is better to avoid `synchronized` if the objects are not shared because `synchronized` is not good for performance. You should start thinking about `synchronized` only when you know that the object will be shared by more than one thread, which is not your case.

EDIT: 
More simple explanation is that this code:

```
public synchronized void meth() {
    ...
}
```

equivalent to:

```
public void meth() {
    synchronized (this){
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: but the synchronized method would be same in this case two thread and two instances of the same class. will it allow to execute synchronized method by two thread as both threads have the lock on objects as per definition if the thread has locked it can enter in synchronized method

Comment: Yes. The method is the same, but every thread holds **different instance**, and `synchronized` **locks** using a monitor associated to the **instance**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That means a synchronized method also can execute by more than one thread at the same time.

Comment: Yes. If these threads holds different instances. Actually it is better to **avoid `synchronized`** if the objects are **not shared** because `synchronized` is not good for performance. You should start thinking about `synchronized` only when you know that the object will be shared by more than one thread.

Comment: Agreed. is it better to use thread local variable which also ensures thread safety and each thread will have own copy of variable and variable will not share among threads. will it be the more better approach

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking a question... it looks like you forget the question mark :) and about deciding the approach, it is depends on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Synchronized methods lock their instance, not the class nor the method (for synchronized static methods, see below...).

So, on a given instance, only one thread can be inside any of its synchronized methods, but that does not block threads working with other instances of the same class.

Synchronized static methods lock the class (they don't have a `this` instance), so of all threads only one at a time can be executing inside a synchronized static method of the given class.

And if you need some other locking scheme, you can use a `synchronized(someObject) { ... }` block, which synchronizes on `someObject`, and then you are free to select the object that represents the mutual-exclusion group.

So, a synchronized method `A.b()` is equivalent to `synchronized(this) {...}` or (in the static case) `synchronized(A.class) {...}`.