# Bytecode size of with brackets vs without brackets in Java

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, jvm-bytecode, javacompiler

Which has a larger bytecode size or the same in Java?

```
if (a > b) a = b;
```

vs

```
if (a > b) {
    a = b;
}
```

Comment: See for yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3315938/is-it-possible-to-view-bytecode-of-class-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These compile to precisely the same thing.

Comment: Thank you.
c = a > b ? a: b;
if (a > b) c = a; else c = b;
Do they also turn into the same byte code?

Comment: Probably not the same bytecode.  Almost certainly exactly the same performance.

Comment: @webelf000 You can find out for yourself by running `javap -c path/to/MyClass.class`

Comment: @webelf000 https://ideone.com/sCGcit

Comment: Thanks, it looks ?: operator is faster and less size than if clause.

Comment: Like I said, "less size" and "faster" are not the same thing.  Bytecode size is virtually meaningless as a measure of performance.

Comment: @webelf000 the method size does not say anything about performance. Most environments have an optimizing Just-In-Time compiler which eliminates such differences anyway. But even if we assume the simplest interpreter, executing these instructions as-is, the *executed instructions* do not differ. Pick either scenario, `a > b` or `a <= b` and go step by step through the code, to check which instructions are actually executed. You’ll see that for each variant, the same instructions are executed, with only one tiny difference in the order, `istore_2, goto` vs `goto, istore_2`. Always the same work…